# how user get token for subsequent request after loging in particular app by Google account

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I'm a newbie in web development. Currently, I've learnt laravel framework and be researching about passport and socialite. I'm being stuck that after logging in the application successfully by their Facebook account how users get the access token for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented using Laravel Socialite. You can follow each step to implement Laravel Socialite.

You will get the information on how to create Secret Key & Access Key for social login.

```
https://github.com/jd-patel/laravel-social-login
```